# How to have Or between vee-validate3 rules?

Tags: vue.js, validation, vee-validate

i have an input that its value can be username or email
consider this:

```html
<ValidationProvider name="email" rules="username || email"    v-slot="{ errors, valid }">
  <v-text-field
    v-model="something"
    :error-messages="errors"
    :success="valid"
    label="E-mail or userName"
    required
  ></v-text-field>
</ValidationProvider>
```

> I need Or between rules. if one of them match pass the input.

**rules="username or email"**
how to achieve this in vee-validate3?

Comment: how do you define the username rule?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim
its a regex:

'^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9._]{8,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[^_.].*[^_.]$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is no or in vee validation
in case you want to or something you have to write custom validator and in the logic of the custom validation you are free to do anything.